# Data Fetched Not Getting to the Client Side

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have an angular application I am creating where I click a page that fetches data from the database but for some weird reason, does not display on the browser. The operation sort of crashes and I click on this particular page and there are no errors logged anywhere, not even on the console or in a text file designed to log all errors/exceptions.

I debugged the C# code on server side and realized the rows are loaded successfully but it doesn't display on the browser and the operation crashes without an error. Please help me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Similar approach of fetching data was used for other pages and they work very well.

**Server Side**

```
        public PagedResultDto<GoodsRequestDto> GetGoodsRequestPaged(GoodsRequestListInput input)
        {
            var goodsRequests = _goodsRequestRepo.GetAllIncluding(g => g.GoodsQuotes)
                .WhereIf(input.UserId.HasValue, g => g.CreatedBy == input.UserId)
                .OrderBy(d => d.Id)
                .PageBy(input)
                .ToList();

            return new PagedResultDto<GoodsRequestDto>
            {
                TotalCount = goodsRequests.Count,
                Items = goodsRequests.MapTo<List<GoodsRequestDto>>()
            };
        }
```

**Angular Controller**

```
           vm.loadGoodsRequests = function () {
                var skipCount = 0;

                abp.ui.setBusy(null,
                    projectService.getGoodsRequestPaged({
                        skipCount: skipCount,
                        userId: appSession.user.id
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        vm.goodsRequests = data.items;
                    })
                );
            }
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-if="vm.goodsRequests.length" ng-repeat="gr in vm.goodsRequests" class="classInfo-list-item col-md-6">
            <div class="classInfo-body">
                <h3 class="classInfo-title">
                    {{gr.categoryItem.name + "_" + gr.brand.name + "_" + gr.product.name | cut:true:50:' ...'}}
                </h3>
                <p class="classInfo-description">Quantity: {{gr.quantity}} {{gr.unit}}</p>
                <p class="classInfo-description">Payment Term: {{gr.paymentTerm}}</p>
                <div class="classInfo-registration-info">
                    {{gr.goodsQuotes.length}} Quote(s).
                </div>
                <div class="classInfo-actions">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-href="#/my-goods-requests/{{gr.id}}">@L("Details") <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
                <span ng-class="vm.statusClass(gr.statusString)" class="classInfo-date"> {{gr.statusString }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the third day on this issue. I am desperate for some help.

Answer (score 0):

The api is returning `Items` not items

So try using `data.Items`

These errors can be easily avoided using browser development tools and the  `debugger;` at the right place ..

hovering on the `data` variable will show you the structure which is returning at run time

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry for my inability to revert promptly it was already very late over here. I don't think that's the problem because I replaced the method with another from the api and it worked even with `data.items`. Something else may be the issue and I can't even get it using the debug.